# Spring MQTT: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat, locale en_US

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-integration, mqtt

NOTE WELL: I am ***NOT*** running eclipse. I am running a standalone Spring application from the command line with maven.

When I attempt to send a message to an outbound channel adapter created with IoC using spring-integration-mqtt 4.3.8, I get

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory.getAsyncClientInstance(DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler.checkConnection(MqttPahoMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler.publish(MqttPahoMessageHandler.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.AbstractMqttMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMqttMessageHandler.java:150)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at com.ssn.nmrlistener.MilliSecurePacketHandler.forwardTrapToChannel(MilliSecurePacketHandler.java:201)
    at com.ssn.nmrlistener.MilliSecurePacketHandler.run(MilliSecurePacketHandler.java:177)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.nls.logcat, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<clinit>(MqttAsyncClient.java:89)
    ... 20 more
```

This suggests I am missing a dependency, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem went away, but I never did figure out what was causing it. My best guess was dependency version classpath pollution - that seems to always be at the bottom of weird Spring behavior (some other dependency will bring in alternate versions of Spring and hilarity ensues).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a corrupt jar in your maven repo? Clearly you have the `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.LoggerFactory` class; I see the logcat bundle in my jar...
[image]